# Insert document with datetime field using the JSON View

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

## Context

On MongoDB Atlas, using the JSON view:
[image]

## Question

I want to insert a document which has a datetime field. I think I need to use the *ISO 8601* format. But I've no idea how it should be formated. The MongoDB documentation doesn't tell a lot about it. I want to do it like this because I'm using the output of a python script but is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Following is working:

```
   db.test.insert({  _id:ObjectId("6027dd515ce9cb94d55744b0") , created_at:ISODate("2021-02-13T15:02:21.565762")   })
   WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
   
   db.test.find()
   { "_id" : ObjectId("6027dd515ce9cb94d55744b0"), "created_at" : ISODate("2021-02-13T15:02:21.566Z") }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60280eb44567b5fc13d18d1e"
    },
    "created_at": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1613224941565"
        }
    }
}
```